Including multiple css statements in Shiny
I'm trying to include two css statements in my shiny app and I know both are valid but only the first one gets included (I know this because I tried switching it around). What am I doing wrong?
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- page_fluid(
  tags$style(".noGap {gap: 0rem};
                  .sw-input-icon {width: 75px};"),
  
  numericInputIcon("height", "Plot Dimension", 400, icon = "Height:"),
  numericInputIcon("width", NULL, 400, icon = "Width:"),
  
  layout_column_wrap(width = 1/2, class = "noGap",
                     card_body(actionButton("a", "a")),
                     card_body(actionButton("b", "b")))
 
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Both elements are included.  You can right-click and choose "inspect element" to see the page.

@user2554330 But why dont I see the changes? I expect the boxes for "Width" and "Height" to be the same, but they are not, the size is not changed when I inspect the element

@user2554330 no, in the above example the second CSS line isn't taken into account.

In your above example the placement of the semicolons is wrong (Also mind the HTML() call):
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- page_fluid(
  tags$style(HTML(".noGap {gap: 0rem;}
                   .sw-input-icon {width: 75px;}")),
  
  numericInputIcon("height", "Plot Dimension", 400, icon = "Height:"),
  numericInputIcon("width", NULL, 400, icon = "Width:"),
  
  layout_column_wrap(width = 1/2, class = "noGap",
                     card_body(actionButton("a", "a")),
                     card_body(actionButton("b", "b")))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)

Please see this article for examples.
